# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject | undefined', Next.js - Chakra UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, eslint, chakra-ui

I am doing a project using Next.js, TypeScript and Chakra UI. In Button themes `button.ts` file, I am getting error in `baseStyle` object for borderRadius, color and border as:

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SystemStyleObject | undefined'.`

Here is the code:

```
import { ComponentMultiStyleConfig } from "@chakra-ui/theme";

export const Button: ComponentMultiStyleConfig = {
    baseStyle: {
        borderRadius: "60px",
        color: "brand.100",
        border: "2px solid red",
    },
};
```

[Code image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6coC.png)

It's not uploading these style to main file.

I have read the documentation and didn't find the answer.

> Edit: In the current(v2.4.9) version of Chakra Ui, instead of `ComponentMultiStyleConfig`, only `useMultiStyleConfig` is used. After  deep digging into documentation and watching some videos, I figured it out. Thank You!

Comment: I have never used chakra-ui myself but maybe you are supposed to use objects like in their [documentation](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/theme#border-radius)

Answer (score 0):

the way you use is not correct. As far as I understood, you are styling different parts of components with this styling. This is the typescript definition:

```
export interface ComponentMultiStyleConfig {
  parts: string[]
  baseStyle?: PartsStyleInterpolation
  sizes?: Record<string, PartsStyleInterpolation>
  variants?: Record<string, PartsStyleInterpolation>
  defaultProps?: ComponentDefaultProps
}
```

As you see `parts` property is mandatory. You are passing parts as string of array and then in `baseStyle` you are writing style for those parts. I think it should be implemented like this:

```
export const Button: ComponentMultiStyleConfig = {
  baseStyle: {
    icon: {
      borderRadius: "60px",
      color: "brand.100",
      border: "2px solid red",
    },
    parts: ["icon"],
  },
};
```

if you write this you will get a typescript issue regarding type of parts but there is an [open issue on github repo](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/issues/6284)